# Connecting to MySQL server from dbeaver gives says Check if "useSSL" is set to "true"

Tags: mysql, dbeaver

I am trying to connect to remote MySQL instace from DBeaver 6.0.4. My connection settings  looks like this:

[image]

Above, the server host is specified as follows:

```
hostxyz.amazonaws.com:443/?verifyServerCertificate=false&useSSL=true&requireSSL=true&trustStore=/ssh-dev/cacerts&trustStorePassword=changeit
```

My driver settings looks like this:

[image]

When I click test connection on Connections Settings page, it gives me following error:

[image]

I wasted several hours to deal with this. How can I fix this?

Comment: Is the answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39514212/ssl-connection-working-in-mysql-workbench-but-not-in-dbeaver/50772020#50772020 working for you?

Comment: able to connect in mysql workbench..dont know whats wrong with dbeaver

Comment: Have you set the SSL required flag in your connection (prior to the "test connection" call)?

Comment: I have specified the connection string above which includes `useSSL=true&requireSSL=true`

Comment: Maybe this setting isn't loaded by DBeaver, what are the settings available in the tabs "Connection properties" and "Adv. parameter"? Are there other locations in DBeaver where you can change the SSL settings of a connection?